# Please specify the identity and function of Metatron in Judaism

Tags: theology, malach-angel

The title is pretty much self-explanatory. I know that Christianity doesn't support the existence of Metatron, as the Scripture in which Metatron is mentioned isn't a part of the Christian Bible. However, some branches of Jewish liturgy might (I don't know so I am asking) bear more specification on this fascinating subject. **Please specify the first mention (chronologically) of the Metatron in the Scripture and comprehensively present his role in the grand scheme of things.**

Thank you in advance.

Comment: This demands a lengthy answer. Did you try researching this yourself?

Comment: Which scriptural references are you aware of?

Comment: @Oliver No, as I don't have much time on my hands. lecture Algebraic Topology at university, so even my best effort can bring the amount of comprehensive information that I can access in this site.

Comment: @mevaqesh Perhpas the "metamorphosis" of Enoch in Genesis 5:24: "Enoch walked faithfully with God; then he was no more, because God took him away."

Comment: @GregorPerčič Scripture doesn't say anything about any metamorphosis; it's a much later interpretation.

Comment: Have you checked out the wikipedia page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metatron? Does it answer your question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first suggested reference to Metatron in what you call *Scripture* is [Bereshit 5:18-24](https://www.sefaria.org/Genesis.5.18?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en). That is what you might refer to as the book of Genesis. That reference is to Chanoch ben Yered. Metatron is also called *the Youth* (הנער) because he took this form after all the other angels had been created and more formally, **מ**טטרון **ש**ר **ה**פנים which is the *Roshei Teivot* of Moshe (**מש״ה**).

As explained in [Otzar Midrashim](https://www.sefaria.org/Otzar_Midrashim,_The_Angel_Metatron_(Chanoch).1?lang=bi), Chanoch was transformed into this angel when ascending above like mentioned in Torah. Because of his state of perfection, his physical body was transformed into the original type of body which Adam HaRishon possessed, namely a body of light.

The first reference as the angel is in Shemot 23:20, like is explained in [Sanhedrin 38b](https://www.sefaria.org/Sanhedrin.38b?lang=bi). Metatron serves as G-d's legal agent to the angels and serves as their King in the angelic order of the universe.

Comment: @Oliver I am not going to enter into a debate about this idea. All Jews understand the meaning of the written Torah as it was taught by Moshe Rabbeinu. That teaching is what is transmitted in the oral Torah, like for example the page from Sanhedrin  cited. When we read Bereshit 5:24, we understand that it is referring to Metatron. There are many sources that explain the details such as Sefer Chanoch and Pirkei Heichalot. But Moshe Rabbeinu taught it to us as stated in the answer.

Comment: There are a handful of holes in your assertions.

Comment: @Oliver - In what ways? Yaacov has sourced all of his claims.

Comment: @ezra His comment; not the answer above. Briefly put: 2nd sentence - it's vague; all Jews understand Torah as written too (אין מקרא יוצא מידי פשוטו). 3rd sentence: "that teaching" - which teaching? Besides, not every story or esoteric teaching in Sanhedrin -or anywhere else- is necessarily considered TSBP mandating acceptance. 4th: who's "we"? I'd venture to say no one, of stature, of rabbinic history ordinarily understands it that way; unless involved in that specific gem. or a cabalistic lesson. 5th: both are traditionally not part of the oral law. 6th: where did Moshe teach this?

Comment: @Oliver - Ah, I see now. Thanks for clearing that up. I do agree with you. I never knew that Chenoch was Metatron until I read this answer and looked into the source material. So saying "we understand" might be a bit out there.